# scanf not reading input the second time

Tags: c, io, scanf

I'm trying to read characters and lines from the standard input, and I'm having trouble.

This is the input I'm trying to read into variables:

```
6 4
engine
brakes
tires
ashtray
vinyl roof
trip computer
Chevrolet
20000.00 3
engine
tires
brakes
Cadillac
70000.00 4
ashtray
vinyl roof
trip computer
engine
Hyundai
10000.00 3
engine
tires
ashtray
Lada
6000.00 1
tires
0 0
```

The first line is two numbers that represent how many parts will be listed, and then how many companies will try and match these parts.

Down six lines is the name of the company trying to match the parts requirements, and the next line after that is two numbers: how much the car will cost, and how many parts requirements the manufacturer can meet.

Then, the parts the manufacturer can put in their car are listed.

Then, comes another manufacturer, the cost of their car, the parts they can meet, a list of the parts, etc.

At the end, I print out who won the bid.

This is the code I'm using to do this:

```
#define MAX_LEN 80

int main(){
    int rfpNum = 0;
    int n, p, reqMet, numMet, nCopy, numActualMet;
    float maxCompliance=-1, lowestBid=-1, tmpCompliance;
  float bid;
    char req[MAX_LEN], bidder[MAX_LEN];
    char winner[MAX_LEN];
    char **reqs;
    char *pos;

    while (scanf("%d %d *[^\n]", &n, &p), (n && p)){
        reqs = new char*[n];
        nCopy = n;

    maxCompliance = -1;

        while (nCopy--){
            fgets(req, MAX_LEN, stdin);
            if ((pos=strchr(req, '\n')) != NULL)
                *pos = '\0';
            reqs[nCopy] = new char[MAX_LEN];
            sprintf(reqs[nCopy], "%s", req);
        }

        while (p--){
            fgets(bidder, MAX_LEN, stdin);
            if ((pos=strchr(bidder, '\n')) != NULL)
                *pos = '\0';

            numActualMet = 0;
            scanf("%f %d *[^\n]", &bid, &numMet);

            while (numMet--){
                fgets(req, MAX_LEN, stdin);
                if ((pos=strchr(req, '\n')) != NULL)
                    *pos = '\0';
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    if (strcmp(req, reqs[i]) == 0) numActualMet++;
                }
            }
            tmpCompliance = (float) numActualMet/n;

            if (tmpCompliance > maxCompliance){
                maxCompliance = tmpCompliance;
                strncpy(winner, bidder, MAX_LEN);
        lowestBid = bid;
            }
            else if ((maxCompliance == tmpCompliance) && (lowestBid == -1 || bid < lowestBid)) {
                lowestBid = bid;
                strncpy(winner, bidder, MAX_LEN);
            }
        }

        rfpNum++;
        if (rfpNum != 1)
            printf("\n");

        printf("RFP #%d\n", rfpNum);
        printf("%s\n", winner);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, I have to enter 0 0 twice before it quits. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

> Problem is, I have to enter 0 0 twice before it quits. Any ideas why?

The line

```
while (scanf("%d %d *[^\n]", &n, &p), (n && p)){
```

expects not only two integers to read into `n` and `p`, it also waits for a non-whitespace character to match with the `*[^\n]` part of the format. If you enter any character, not just `0 0`, the program will stop. I was able to terminate it by entering `abc`.

A better method is to use `fgets()` followed by `sscanf`.

```
char buffer[100]; // Make it large enough
while ( fgets(buffer, 100, stdin) != NULL )
{
   int n = sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &n, &p);
   if ( n != 2 )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }

   if ( n == 0 && p == 0 )
   {
      break;
   }

  // Rest of the loop

}
```

As a policy, try to avoid mixing `fgets` and `fscanf`. When used together, they are fraught with problems.